# Cannot fetch data from my database

Tags: php, mysql, parse-error

Below is the code snippet I have used to fetch some data from the MySQL database but I'm getting an error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\test\..\line28
```

That code snippet is given below. Any suggestions?

```
if (($_POST["status"]) === "Builder" ) {
    $sql_1= "SELECT `email_address` from `buider_basic_info` where `email_address` ='$_POST[username]'";
    echo $sql_1;
}
```

Comment: you need to have quotes around strings

Comment: you need to protect your POST variables from being used for SQL injection attacks...

Comment: Always use parameterized statements instead of string pasting; this is asking for [a SQL injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/) when you get a creative value for `username`.

Answer (score 0):

-- you can't use quotes in table name or any column name. you can use backtick.
-- your query is string so it should be inside quotes.
-- use quotes for email address as it is a string

try this:

```
  $sql_1=" SELECT `email_address` 
    from `buider_basic_info` 
    where `email_address` = '".$_POST['username']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql_1= 
"SELECT `email_address` from `buider_basic_info` where
`email_address`='". $_POST['username']."'";
```

Use backtics instead of single quote for field name

Comment: Have you used backtics for field name?

Comment: echo $sql_1 and what it display?

Comment: doesn't go dat far... stops on the line before it.. giving the specified error.

Comment: What are you written on 28th line?

Comment: $sql_1= "SELECT email_address from buider_basic_info where email_address ='$_POST[username]'";

Comment: and now... $sql_1= 
"SELECT `email_address` from `buider_basic_info` where
`email_address`='". $_POST['username']."'";

Comment: This one is correct so you have to debug your code some where you are missing semicolon or parenthesis

Comment: Always use parameterized statements instead of string pasting; this is asking for [a SQL injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/) when you get a creative value for `username`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_1 = "SELECT email_address
          FROM buider_basic_info
          WHERE email_address = '".$_POST['username']."'";
```